# I keep getting TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert temperature to either Celcius or Fahrenheit and below is my code:

```
temp = eval(input('Enter a temperature: '))
unit = input('C(Cel) or F(Faren): ')
if unit.upper() == 'C':
  celcius = 5/9(temp-32)
  print(celcius)
else:
  fahrenheit = 9/5(temp+32)
  print(fahrenheit)
```

But I keep getting this output:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Please how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> 5/9(temp-32)

I assume you wanted to multiply here, the right thing to do it
`5/9 * (temp-32)`, same with `9/5 * (temp+32)`

Also, replace `temp = eval(input('Enter a temperature: '))`
with `temp = int(input('Enter a temperature: '))`

`eval` is super dangerous since it can let the user of the program run anything on your computer, you should almost always avoid it

Answer (score 0):

Both `celcius = 5/9(temp-32)` and `fahrenheit = 9/5(temp+32)` are mistyped. Python now thinks it's a function. U need to add the multiplication charcter `*` like this:

```
temp = int(input('Enter a temperature: '))
unit = input('C(Cel) or F(Faren): ')
if unit.upper() == 'C':
  celcius = 5/9*(temp-32)
  print(celcius)
else:
  fahrenheit = 9/5*(temp+32)
  print(fahrenheit)
```

Notice that I also changed your `eval(...)` to int(...) this converts the string output of `input(...)`to an integer, which you need to perform mathematical actions. Added benefit is that the removal of `eval()` makes your code a whole lot safer.